# Libgdx robovm ios bindings for IAP

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, robovm

I want to implement ios In app purchase in my `libgdx` game. Im using `Android studio`

I'm searching for robovm ios bindings, but only that I found is https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings , but this  bindings are deprecated. On suggested link https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods there isn't any binding for ios IAP.

Is there any other working binding for this purpose?
Can I use (and how) this deprecated `BlueRiverInteractive` binding in my `Android Studio` project?

I don't want to use `gdx-pay` because I don't want to change my android part of my game (I already have implemented android in app purchase for google play store)

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoboVM has now a new RoboPod called Robo.Billing which allows you to implement cross-platform in app purchases in your app:
https://github.com/robovm/robovm-robopods/tree/master/components/robo.billing

There is no documentation yet, but you can take a look at the sample app:
https://github.com/robovm/robovm-samples/tree/snapshot/robopods/components/robo.billing

Take a look at the the core project of the sample. You can do all in app purchasing in the core project, you do not need to change any code in your iOS project.
If you also want to let Robo.Billing handle Android IAPs you will have to implement some code in `onActivityResult` or your launch activity (just check the android project of the sample).

Also don't forget to add the necessary dependencies to your build.gradle:

```
core: compile "org.robovm:robopods-billing-core:1.13.1-SNAPSHOT"
ios: compile "org.robovm:robopods-billing-ios:1.13.1-SNAPSHOT"
android: compile "org.robovm:robopods-billing-android:1.13.1-SNAPSHOT"
```